Flink web file upload to GKE persistent volume returns file upload error
I deployed Flink on GKE and and created a persistent volume that I attached to the job manager deployment.
Web file uploads work fine when it's uploaded to the container's ephemeral filesystem, but when I specify web.upload.dir: /path/to/my/volume and upload a file it returns {"errors":["File upload failed."]}, and the job manager's logs don't show any errors.
I changed the path to point to the container's ephemeral storage and then it worked, so it seems like the issue is with the persistent volume, even though I ssh-ed into the container and could successfully create files and directories.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
